# How to create Jersey 2 client with Executor

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have created a jersey 2 client with the below code,

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 5000);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
Client client =  ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

I can able to make request and every thing works fine. But I want to control the number of client execution thread. In jersey 1, we can have the same implementation like below,

```
Client client =  Client.create();
client.setConnectTimeout(5000);
client.setReadTimeout(10000);
client.setExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
```

I want to replicate the same thing,

> client.setExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

with jersey 2 client.

After some search I found [this](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/12e5d8bdf22bcd2676a1032ed69473cf2bbc48c7/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java#L71) for jersey 2. But it is available 
in latest version of jersey 2 (2.26). I am using [2.25.1](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25.1/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java#L63) jersey version. How to achieve the same for 2.25.1 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just digging through the source and found [`ExecutorServiceProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25.1/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/spi/ExecutorServiceProvider.java) and [`@ClientAsyncExecutor`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25.1/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientAsyncExecutor.java). If you implement the former and annotate it with the latter, your executor should be used as long as the request is *asynchronous* (I noticed prior to your edit that you were looking for *synchronous*) and you register the provider with the client.

```
@ClientAsyncExecutor
static class MyExecutorServiceProvider implements ExecutorServiceProvider {

    @Override
    public ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        System.out.println("Calling getExecutorService()");
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ExecutorService executorService) {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
client.register(new MyExecutorServiceProvider());

Future<Response> res = client.target("test").async().get()
```

Comment: hmm. Is it possible to do the same without using **ExecutorServiceProvider** interface? I have instance of **ExecutorService**  and I want to register directly without wrapping with **ExecutorServiceProvider** for some reason. Possible?